# Application starting twice without environment properties on the second startup

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, tomcat8

Our Spring Boot application is getting started twice but without the environment setup on the second startup. So on the second startup the application fails to start. We need to setup the application from the external tomcat config directory. In order to get the logging working correctly, we have the following setup.

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.14.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>foo.bar.MyApplication</start-class>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.32</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Environment -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

## main-class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);

    public MyApplication() {
        LOG.info(">>>>>>>>>>> Welcome to MyApplication");
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return configureApplication(builder);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        configureApplication(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
    }

    private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureApplication(final SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public MyBean getMyBean() {
        LOG.debug("Created request scoped MyBean.");
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

## server.xml (stripped down)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="${tomcat.shutdown.port}" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

    <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" />

    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

    <Service name="Catalina">

        <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            redirectPort="${environment.https.redirect.port}" server="Apache" />
        <Connector port="9080" protocol="AJP/1.3"
            redirectPort="${environment.https.redirect.port}" />

        <Engine defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="${servername}" name="Catalina">

            <Host appBase="${tomcat.webapp.dir}" autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true"
                xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">

                <Context docBase="my-app" path="/myapp" reloadable="true">
                    <Parameter name="spring.config.location" value="file:C:/tomcat/conf/" />
                    <Parameter name="spring.config.name" value="myapp" /> <!-- results in myapp.properties -->
                    <Parameter name="org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH" value="true" />
                </Context>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

## log

```
Jul 16, 2018 10:17:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.4 using APR version 1.5.1.
Jul 16, 2018 10:17:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Jul 16, 2018 10:17:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015)
Jul 16, 2018 10:17:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8081"]
Jul 16, 2018 10:17:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-9080"]
Jul 16, 2018 10:17:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1404 ms
Jul 16, 2018 10:17:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 16, 2018 10:17:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
Jul 16, 2018 10:17:25 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 16, 2018 10:17:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.14.RELEASE)

2018-07-16 10:17:27.316  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] f.b.MyApplication                        : Starting MyApplication v1.0.2-SNAPSHOT on tomcat with PID 4880 (C:\tomcat\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\classes started by admin in C:\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse)
2018-07-16 10:17:27,362 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Unable to create directory C:\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\${sys:LOG_PATH}\2018-07
2018-07-16 10:17:27.362 DEBUG 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] f.b.MyApplication                        : Running with Spring Boot v1.5.14.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.18.RELEASE
2018-07-16 10:17:27.378  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] f.b.MyApplication                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-16 10:17:27.472  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@f7cbaab2: startup date [Mon Jul 16 10:17:27 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-16 10:17:29.562  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ddbcd45] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-16 10:17:29.859  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/myapp]                   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-16 10:17:29.859  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.ContextLoader                    : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2387 ms
2018-07-16 10:17:30.483  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-07-16 10:17:30.483  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 10:17:30.483  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 10:17:30.483  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 10:17:30.483  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 10:17:30.483  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
com.ibm.net.SocketKeepAliveParameters
2018-07-16 10:17:39.501  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-16 10:17:42.903  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-16 10:17:42.919  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] f.b.MyApplication                        : >>>>>>>>>>> Welcome to MyApplication
2018-07-16 10:17:44.714  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@f7cbaab2: startup date [Mon Jul 16 10:17:27 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-16 10:17:44.917  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/root],methods=[GET]}" [...]
2018-07-16 10:17:45.120  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping        : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-07-16 10:17:45.120  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping        : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-07-16 10:17:45.214  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping        : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-07-16 10:17:45.651  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-07-16 10:17:46.151  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] f.b.MyApplication                        : Started MyApplication in 19.788 seconds (JVM running for 32.145)
2018-07-16 10:17:46.166  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.s.HostConfig                       : Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat\webapps\myapp
2018-07-16 10:17:53.420  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.j.s.TldScanner                       : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2018-07-16 10:17:53.718  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/myapp]                   : 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.14.RELEASE)

2018-07-16 10:17:54.435  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] f.b.MyApplication                        : Starting MyApplication v1.0.2-SNAPSHOT on tomcat with PID 4880 (C:\tomcat\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\classes started by admin in C:\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse)
2018-07-16 10:17:54.451  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] f.b.MyApplication                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-16 10:17:54.530  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@8cc9db4a: startup date [Mon Jul 16 10:17:54 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-16 10:17:56.308  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5095fdde] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-16 10:17:56.575  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/myapp]                   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-16 10:17:56.575  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.ContextLoader                    : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2045 ms
2018-07-16 10:17:57.136  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-07-16 10:17:57.136  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 10:17:57.136  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 10:17:57.136  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 10:17:57.136  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 10:17:57.136  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 10:17:57.214  WARN 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2018-07-16 10:17:57.230  INFO 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-16 10:17:57.230 ERROR 4880 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

## cause of error

The configuration setup as context properties in the server.xml (`spring.config.location` & `spring.config.name`) are not being taken into account on the second start. So the Spring Boot application has no myapp.properties available and thererfore spring-boot-starter-data-jpa cannot find any configuration for the DataSource setup and fails on initialization.

## analysis

I have researched the log entry about the two WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath. This is not the cause of this behavior. There are two WebApplicationInitializers:

- `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration.JerseyWebApplicationInitializer`
- `foo.bar.MyApplication`

The Jersey-initializer comes from the dependency: spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar and the code about it states:

```
// We need to switch *off* the Jersey WebApplicationInitializer because it
// will try and register a ContextLoaderListener which we don't need
servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "<NONE>");
```

The Jersey WebApplicationInitializer does basically nothing and this is not the reason for this behavior.

So I researched the stacktraces of this behavior and got the following result:

Set a breakpoint on `org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Set<Class<?>>, ServletContext)`

### first startup

```
SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Set<Class<?>>, ServletContext) line: 169    
StandardContext.startInternal() line: 5244  
StandardContext(LifecycleBase).start() line: 147    
ContainerBase$StartChild.call() line: 1408  
ContainerBase$StartChild.call() line: 1398  
FutureTask<V>.run() line: 277   
ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1153  
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 628   
Thread.run() line: 785
```

### second startup

```
SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Set<Class<?>>, ServletContext) line: 169    
StandardContext.startInternal() line: 5244  
StandardContext(LifecycleBase).start() line: 147    
StandardHost(ContainerBase).addChildInternal(Container) line: 725   
StandardHost(ContainerBase).addChild(Container) line: 701   
StandardHost.addChild(Container) line: 717  
HostConfig.deployDirectory(ContextName, File) line: 1091    
HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run() line: 1830 
Executors$RunnableAdapter<T>.call() line: 522   
FutureTask<V>.run() line: 277   
ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1153  
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 628   
Thread.run() line: 785
```

According to the second stacktrace, tomcat - for some reason - wants to deploy the directory /tomcat/webapps/myapp again and this time the context properties from the server.xml are not being used.

## hint

We are using `spring.config.location`instead of `@PropertySources` because of we need full control over the logging. Property sources are loaded may too late and are no option at all.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself. The cause was the tomcat server itself. There was a misconfiguration. Since this is not a standard tomcat installation (customer specialization) it does not make much sense to explain the solution here.

Comment: I would like to hear your solution as I am having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having two child classes of SpringBootServletInitializer. And one of the class might missing @Configuration. If you want to run two instance then make sure you have @Configuration on both child classes of SpringBootServletInitializer. If you want to run single instance then remove second inheritance.